# Most Lightweight Java Collection

Tags: java, optimization, collections

If I am going to create a  Java Collection, and only want to fill it with elements, and then iterate through it (without knowing the necessary size beforehand), i.e. all I need is `Collection<E>.add(E)` and `Collection<E>.iterator()`, which concrete class should I choose? Is there any advantage to using a `Set` rather than a `List`, for example? Which one would have the least overhead?

Comment: I suggest you go read about the different types of collections and how they're implemented. The type of collection is entirely dependent on the specific application. There are definitely advantages of a set over a list, but a set isn't just a drop in replacement for a list. They serve different purposes.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

> ***which concrete class should I choose?***

I would probably just go with an [`ArrayList`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) or a [`LinkedList`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html). Both support the `add` and `iterator` methods, and neighter of them have any considerable overhead.

> ***Is there any advantage to using a Set rather than a List, for example?***

No, I wouldn't say so. (Unless you rely on the order of the elements, in which case you must use a List, or want to disallow duplicates, in which case you should use a Set.)

(I don't see how any Set implementation could beat a list implementation for add / iterator methods, so I'd probably go with a List even if I don't care about order.)

> ***Which one would have the least overhead?***

Sounds like micro benchmarking here, but if I'd be forced to guess, I'd say ArrayList (or perhaps LinkedList in coner cases where ArrayLists need to reallocate memory often :-)

Comment: Pretty much. If all you ever want to do is add and iterate, the world is your oyster.

Comment: Depending on the size an ArrayList is usually much more memory and performance efficient

Comment: @pvblivs What kind of size threshhold are we talking?

Comment: I did the performance test once. We talk about sth. like 11 elements. Because that is the moment when an ArrayList needs to grow first. I have not met a situation yet where a LinkedList fitted any better than an ArrayList, just because the latter is the better general-purpose Collection

Answer (score 3):

Do not go with a `Set`. Sets and Lists differ according to their purpose, that you should always consider when choosing the right `Collection`

- a `List` is there for maintaining elements in the order you added them; and if you insert the same element twice it will be kept twice
- a `Set` is there for holding one specific element exactly once (uniqueness); order is only relevant for specific implementations (like `TreeSet`), but still elements that are 'the same' would not be added twice

Answer (score 2):

`Set` is only meaningful if you want to sort your objects and to make sure no duplicate  element is 'registered'. Else, an `ArrayList` is just fine.

However, if you want to add elements while iterating too, an `ArrayBlockingQueue` is better.

Answer (score 1):

Here are some key points which can help you to choose your collection according to your requirement -

1. List(ArrayList or LinkedList)

   - Allowed duplicate values.
   - Insertion order preserved.
2. Set

   - Not allowed duplicate values.
   - Insertion order is not preserved.

So according to your requirement List seems to be a suitable choice.

**Now Between ArrayList and LinkedList -**

ArrayList is a random access list. Use if your frequent operation is the retrieval of elements.

LinkedList is the best option if you want to add or remove elements from the list.